# Usar dominio para un subdominio de un multisitio WP

Tags: wordpress, nginx, dns

procedo a explicar: Tengo montado en local con nginx un multisitio wordpress con dos páginas, la principal > mysite.net, y un subdominio > loquesea.mysite.net

Hasta ahí está todo perfecto, cada uno entra a su correspondiente página con su respectiva URL y su respectivo certificado SSL.

El problema viene cuando quiero que ese subdominio loquesea.mysite.net quede por debajo de un dominio más profesional, o sea, que entrando por ejemplo a loquesea.net en realidad estés entrando a loquesea.mysite.net

Estoy usando dos dominios gratuitos de Freenom, el dominio principal donde tengo configurada las DNS para el multisitio y su subdominio correspondiente, que como ya dije funcionan correctamente. Y por otra parte el dominio que quiero usar para el subdominio del dominio anterior. Y he intentado configurar de mil maneras las DNS pero no lo consigo. En el uno, y en el otro pero al final no lo consigo.

Si en el dominio loquesea.net, apunto con un A-RECORD a la IP de mi servidor, deja de funcionar ya que acaban tanto el subdominio como el dominio principal apuntando a la página del dominio principal.

Si en el dominio loquesea.net, apunto con un CNAME a la dirección del subdominio de mysite.net que es loquesea.mysite.net, no entra.

Si en el dominio mysite.net, donde tengo todas las DNS configuradas para el sitio principal, también intento poner por ejemplo un CNAME de loquesea.mysite.net a loquesea.net y tampoco funciona.

Y ahí ya me quedé, no sé que más probar sinceramente, ya que la otra opción que me queda es la del URL Forwarding cloaking pero sinceramente no me gusta. Prefiero que la URL sea dinámica al sitio que apunta.

Muchas gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: a) Un DNSmasq, b) una redirección, c) revisaste cómo se está resolviendo cada dominio al configurarlo? Cuando haces ping o telnet al puerto 80, resuelve la IP que esperas?

Comment: La redirección no es lo que busco como ya comenté. He hecho ping y todo correcto, pero al dominio que tengo preparado para el subdominio del multisitio, me devuelve: DNS: Could not find host - loquesea.net, aborting. Parece ser que es porque en la conf. DNS de ese dominio, no tengo apuntando ningún A-RECORD, pero es que como dije, si apunto a la IP, entonces tanto mysite.net y loquesea.net apuntan al mismo sitio, o sea a la web principal, a la de mysite.net 

No sé si es que aparte del A-RECORD necesita también apuntar al dominio con CNAME o eso lo hago en el otro dominio, esa es la duda.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIÓN: Una vez tengamos dominio.net y sub.dominio.net, y queremos apuntar ese sub.dominio.net a otrodominio.net debemos de:

1. En dominio.net apuntamos desde el nombre del subdominio: (sub), a la IP del host mediante un A-Record.

SUB | A | IP

2. En otrodominio.net apuntamos desde root a la IP del host mediante un A-Record.

@ | A | IP

3. En la configuración de los multisitios, cambiar la dirección del subdominio que apuntamos antes por la del nuevo dominio.

De sub.dominio.net a otrodominio.net

Y YA ESPERAR QUE TODO SE ASIENTE. Dependiendo del TTL, yo lo pongo a 300, o sea 5 minutos, y pasado ese tiempo ya deberíamos tener dos sitios independientes con URL's independientes en un multisitio de WP.

Saludos.